# Limitar o tamanho do LinkedHashMap

Tags: java

Preciso limitar o tamanho da saída do meu LinkedHashMap:
Ele recebe um numero indeterminado de informações que precisam ser reduzidas a no max 20 registros: 
Coloquei um limit na função abaixo, porem nao tive resultados.

```
Map <String, ReportLine> map = new LinkedHashMap();
                    skuOrderCount.entrySet().stream()
                            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.comparing(ReportLine::getTotalCount).reversed()))
                            .limit(20)
                            .forEach(entry -> {
                                map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                            });
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao invés de adicionar os valores em um mapa externo, você deve utilizar as próprias operações de saída das streams.

No seu caso isso será resolvido coletando o resultado do `limit` da seguinte forma:

```
Map<String, ReportLine> myNewMap = skuOrderCount.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.comparing(ReportLine::getTotalCount).reversed()))
                .limit(20).collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

Você pode conferir as operações terminais e intermediárias na [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)

Comment: na realidade o erro era inteiramente meu, nem foi necessário utilizar da sua logica.Meu erro foi iterrar em um forEach a instancia do meu linkedList, ao invez do map mostrado acima. Mas muito obrigado ermão.abrrss